# Django: passing parameters not inside the URL

Tags: django

Right now I have a very long URL for my results which is basically a long list of parameters. I navigate to the results by press of a button and (JavaScript):

```
window.location.href = ... URL with parameters here ...;
```

Catching them like this (views.py):

```
def Results(request,parameter1,...,parameterN)
```

How do I send these same parameters not inside the URL and how do I catch them in views?

EDIT:

To clarify, in a an optimal world I'd like to send the parameters hidden from the user and search engine crawlers so that the user/crawler sees only the URL:

```
www.example.com/results
```

And I do something like:

```
def Results(request):
    parameter1 = ???
    parameter2 = ???
    ...
    parameterN = ???
```

Comment: Hard to say without a clearer example (imo), Why do you need so many parameters? are they all required?

Comment: What exactly you want and also specify Method which you are using (GET or POST).

Comment: @Sayse all the parameters are required. The results page makes a computation using all of them (physics data).

Comment: @Kjjassy I just paste the code to change the URL inside the button code that works on a click. I am not sure if this is GET or POST how do I tell? (I don't want to use the same method, I want them to be passed HIDDEN from the user).

Comment: Are you using jquery or anything or just VanillaJS?

Comment: `HIDDEN` -> so use a html form and put your values hidden in the form and submit the form. Then access values using `request.POST.get('name', None);`

Comment: @user1581390 would you mind check my answer?

Comment: @MehranTorki there is a small typo a '=' is missing here: value""/>. Apart from that this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you need to hide parameters, you should send `POST` request. To send parameters using `POST` method, you can send them using html `form` element or `javascript`. For example you can pass parameters with `form` like this :

```
<form id="my_form" action="/results" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="param1" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="param2" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="param3" value=""/>
</form>
```

Populate hidden `input` elements in javascript like this:

```
var my_form = document.forms['my_form'];
my_form.elements["param1"].value = "Some Value1";
my_form.elements["param2"].value = "Some Value2";
my_form.elements["param3"].value = "Some Value3";
```

And to submit the form in javascript :

```
document.getElementById("my_form").submit();
```

Then access parameters in `view` :

```
def Results(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        parameter1 = request.POST.get("param1", None)
        parameter2 = request.POST.get("param2", None)
        parameter3 = request.POST.get("param3", None)
    else:
        # handle get request
```

Read here if you want to send `POST` request using javascript: [Sending an HTTP Post using Javascript triggered event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873443/sending-an-http-post-using-javascript-triggered-event)

Answer (score 2):

You access the url parameters in the GET dictionary

```
www.example.com/?parm1=baz&&parm2=baz
```

In the view:

```
def ViewFunction(request):   
   parm1 = request.GET['parm1']
   parm2 = request.GET['parm2']
```

If these parameters are optional, you will want to use a default, like:

```
parm1 = request.GET.get('parm1',None)
```

Note that **the GET parameters are not safe**. You should escape them properly before using them in the code. An easy solution is to use a django form, pass the GET values to the form, and then use the `form.cleaned_data`.

When you have too many parameters, check your view and urls, maybe you can convert some parameters to a url captured args.

Comment: But how do I send them without the long URL with the parameters in it?