# Passing variables from application.html.erb to controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables

I have a variable inside `application.html.erb`'s `<script>`:

```
...
<script>
  ...
  pos = {
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lng: position.coords.longitude
  };
  ...
</script>
```

Is there a way to pass it down to one of my controllers (`posts_controller.rb`)'s method (`some_method`)?

I need to get both latitude and longitude that is generated inside the script into `posts_controller`. How can I do this?

EDIT: *(I didn't mention it, but `some_method` does not use `get 'some_method'`, but `post`)*

```
#routes
post 'some_method' => 'posts#scrape', as: :some_method
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## GET request

You could use

```
window.open("/posts/some_method?longitude="+pos['lng']+"&latitude="+pos['lat'],"_self")
```

inside your `<script>`.

## POST request

With [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), you could use :

```
$.post("/posts/some_method?longitude="+pos['lng']+"&latitude="+pos['lat'])
```

For vanilla javascript, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14882783/6419007).

In `some_method`, `longitude` and `latitude` will be available in `params[:longitude]` and `params[:latitude]`.

You can set instance variables (e.g. `@lat` and `@lon`) inside `some_method`, and those variables will be available in the corresponding view.

Comment: Hi Eric! Thanks for the response. I did not elaborate (which is entirely my fault), but some_method is not a GET request, but a POST request. Can you suggest another method to pass down variable to a non-GET method? I edited my post to add the method.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry that I keep asking, but now that I used jquery to post `longitude` and `latitude` attributes for `Post`, how can I capture it on `some_method` (and display it on views?) Much appreciate the help!