# Triggering a Data Factory Pipeline through javascript

Tags: javascript, json, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

I have made this pipeline in Azure Data Factory that copies data from a Azure Storage Table to a Azure SQL database Table.

The Azure storage table is given data from a Javascript chatbot that records answers and stores them in the table. I would like to trigger the CopyTabletoSQL 
through my javascript app once all of the answers have been recorded.

This is my CopyTableToSQL pipeline object.

```
{
"name": "CopyTabletoSQL",
"type": "Copy",
"policy": {
    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
    "retry": 0,
    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
    "secureOutput": false
},
"typeProperties": {
    "source": {
        "type": "AzureTableSource"
    },
    "sink": {
        "type": "SqlSink",
        "writeBatchSize": 10000
    },
    "enableStaging": false,
    "dataIntegrationUnits": 0
},
"inputs": [
    {
        "referenceName": "tableInputDataset",
        "type": "DatasetReference"
    }
],
"outputs": [
    {
        "referenceName": "OutputSqlTable1",
        "type": "DatasetReference"
    }
]
}
```

Is there any way to have this execute from a javascript app? The docoumentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers) only mentions .net, Powershell, REST API and Python SDK but nothing for node.js

Comment: I have managed to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/createrun

to create a run and try it and it was succesfull. 

POST -URL-
Authorization: Bearer -random symbols-
Content-type: application/json
How would I go about implementing this into my javascript app so that I can call on it at the end of a run of my app? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Azure Data Factory nodejs sdk is not supported so far. Based on your description, you already have created pipeline in your adf account.You could use Azure Data Factory [Pipelines - Create Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/createrun) REST api to execute it.

In this process, you need to generate Authorization token in Headers. You could refer to [ADAL nodejs sdk](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs#server-to-server-via-client-credentials) to generate token.

Before that, you need to grant adf permission to your ad app.

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I have managed to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/createrun

to create a run and try it and it was succesfull. 

POST -URL-
Authorization: Bearer -random symbols-
Content-type: application/json

How would I go about implementing this into my javascript app so that I can call on it at the end of a run of my app?

Many thanks!

Comment: @BergBerg You could send post request with Authorization token in your js app. About generating token, please refer to the sdk mentioned in my above answer.

Comment: Thank you for all your help/trouble! I found this: https://pastebin.com/urtabdvL

from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873443/sending-an-http-post-using-javascript-triggered-event

Everything seems to be fine however, I am not sure what to write in 

`var postData = "Some data";`
I'm guessing it is somehow related to the JSON body?

also would I need to add 

`Authorization: Bearer -random symbols-`
somehow?

I will look at the SDK you mentioned regarding how to generate a token!

Many Thanks!

Comment: For the post data, you could just reference what UI sent out. I think an empty object {} should work if you don’t need pass parameter value.

Comment: For some added context: This is how my app looks like right now, https://pastebin.com/fbp3ddzD . I've built it following guides and how to's from the microsoft documents and some googleing/ stackoverflow. It is a simple chatbot that asks 3 questions, records the answers and then I have a pipeline that copies the answers from my table to a SQL database. Everything works fine, the bot asks and records the answers, and the pipeline copies them to my SQL database, I'm looking for a way to trigger the copy from table to database automaticly once a conversation have been finished.

Answer (score 0):

You could call rest api in JavaScript.